# Отсутствует файл App.config

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании проекта , у меня нет  файла App.config . Как решить этот вопрос ?

Comment: .NET Framework или .NET 5?

Comment: У проектов созданных для `.NET 5` или `.NET Core 3` нет файла `App.config`. Да и зачем он вам нужен? Читаете какую-нибудь устаревшую книгу что-ли?

Comment: `Как решить этот вопрос ?` добавьте файлик сами, какие проблемы?